# Cannot add the SSH public key to another GitHub account and be able to use it?

Tags: git, github

I am trying some simple code sample and I could push to my work's GitHub account if I want to, but since it is just some code sample, I thought I could just push to my personal GitHub account.

So I look at my `~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub` file, and add that content to my personal GitHub account's SSH key.

So I thought I should be able to push there (after creating a new repo).  But in Bash, it always asked me for user name and password.

How can this problem be solved?  I think what the problem could be is, the email at the end of `~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub` is like `susan@mycompany.com`, but my GitHun account is like `susan123@gmail.com` (just a made up account name), but somebody told me the email address doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggesting starting with a `git remote -v` to see what protocol you're using on `origin` remote.

I suspect that you configured it for HTTPS and not SSH. Switching your remote `origin` would therefore pass your SSH keys in the authentication process.

Take a look at this [page](https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/managing-remote-repositories#changing-a-remote-repositorys-url), which explains how to change the remote to use SSH. You will need to do something like:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```

Comment: it is a new repo, so Github already suggested using `git remote add origin https://github.com/susan123/Try.git`... so it is `https` but not `ssh`? That's weird... on one github account, it did suggest using `git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git` but this one is `https://github.com/susan123/Try.git`. How come it is random?

Comment: When you look at the clone option you can change between SSH and HTTPS (and also GitHub CLI). So all of those commands are available.

Comment: you know how you create a new repo on GitHub... on my one account, it suggested using for an existing project, `git remote add origin git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git` but this one, it is suggesting using `git remote add origin https://github.com/susan123/Try.git`... (and then the `git push`)... since I don't usually look carefully and just copy and paste those two lines over, that's why it is happening. But why suggest https on one account and ssh on the other?

Comment: This might be caching issue from a past selection. Regardless, did my above answer fixed the issue?

Comment: Yes. I found on the top panel, there is a choice for HTTPS and SSH. If I choose one of them, the command line in the 3rd panel changes too.  And let's say I choose SSH, and then I create a new project, and then this time, it defaults to SSH. So confusing.

Comment: It might be based on a last choice (perhaps it thinks that this if going to be your default choice). It's a good thing you are doing SSH as authentication via username/password for `git` actions will be disabled later this year.

Comment: Ok, and it might also be due to the repo was created before I added any SSH key. Perhaps if I added an SSH key first and then created the project, then it would default to the SSH option (which I think is more common)